# Not able to get data from JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

*This may be duplicate question because I am not sure what I have to search to get the solution*

I am working on JSON, Array and Parsing of strings daily, so it is not too lengthy for me to get values from API but here I am confused now. I am getting this JSON string from my api, below is a some values of my whole response

```
{
    "data": {
        "6402902233557646": {
            "_geo_node": {
                "name": "Dev",
                "tags": {
                    "property_type": ["Dev"],
                    "_listing_type": ["_main"],
                    "others": ["_hotel"]
                },
                "raw_tags": [],
                "location": {
                    "lat": 22.9745967,
                    "long": 72.5615485
                },
                "_id": "6402902233557646",
                "type": 120
            },
            "_data_node": {
                "rating": 0,
                "img_processed": [],
                "name": "Dev",
                "ids": {},
                "st": "LIV",
                "_id": "6402902233557646"
            }
        },
        "6402902233557647": {},
        "6402902233557648": {},
        "6402902233557649": {}
    }, 
    "t": 1144.423, 
    "success": true 
}
```

And I am trying to get single values from this as I have tried below different terms for this

```
var getData = JSON.parse(response); //Error: Already Parsed

alert(response.success); //OK true
alert(response.t); //OK 1144.423
```

**Here is a problem**

```
alert(response.data.length) //Undefined
alert(response.data) // [object,object]
alert(response.data[0]["_geo_node"]["name"]); //TypeError: response.data[0] is undefined
```

I am not sure that why I am getting this undefined or where I missed the points

Comment: `response.data` is not an array.its an object.

Comment: Terminology pedantry: [there's no such thing as a "JSON object".](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: It is really good for me to understand this, I have got this type of api first time but next I will surely work on this for more. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`response.data` is not an array, it is a javascript object. It doesn't have a `length` property, so that's why that is undefined, and it also doesn't have a `0` property.

It does have a `6402902233557646` property, for instance, so you would be able to access `response.data['6402902233557646']._geo_node.name`.

You can get a collection of all properties in the object by using `Object.keys(response.data)`. Thus you could also access `response.data[Object.keys(response.data)[0]]._geo_node.name`. Note that since your object is not an array, the items have no inherent order. Do not rely on the first item in `Object.keys()` to always be the first element you've defined in your object. If order is important, rewrite your object into an array.

Answer (score 1):

Non.array objects cannot be accesed via the number as index.

You can itterate through it with the "in" keyword.

E.g.:

```
for (i in data)
  console.log(i)
```

Comment: *"Non.array objects cannot be accesed via the number as index."* - Except when they can. `{ 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'etc.' }`

Comment: True but this applies only to the subset of objects that have keys enumerated from 0,1,2... n-1,n , n being integer

Answer (score 0):

You are probably expecting an array of objects, a very common JSON data format as input, wherein you could have iterated over the object using .length in a for loop.

You could find the length of this object with a **Object.keys(data)** and then doing a .length on the resulting array.
To iterate, you could use the **hasOwnProperty** method wih appropriate keys.

More like

```
for (var key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
  {
       console.log(data["data"]["whatever key"]);
  }
}
```